# Confusion about Hatcher's example involving a chain complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

On pg 190 of Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology", in the chapter "Cohomology", the following claim is made:

> Consider the chain complex $$0\to \Bbb{Z}\xrightarrow{0}\Bbb{Z}\xrightarrow{2}\Bbb{Z}\xrightarrow{0}\Bbb{Z}\to 0$$ The homology groups are $\Bbb{Z}$'s in dimensions $0$ and $3$.

I am assuming that the map $0$ is just multiplication of all elements of $\Bbb{Z}$ by $0$. Similarly, the map $2$ is just multiplication by $2$. How are the dimensions of the homology groups $0$ and $3$? It seems to be that for the first $\Bbb{Z}$ in the chain complex, the dimension of the homology group is $1$.

Comment: "Dimension" is a confusing word to use here; Hatcher means $\mathbb{Z}$ occurs in degree $0$ and degree $3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that $H_0$ and $H_3$ are equal to $\mathbb Z$.
Allan Hatcher also tells that $H_1=\mathbb Z_2$ when he writes "together with a $\mathbb Z_2$ in dimension 1".

Comment: Ah. So "in dimensions $0$ and $3$" just refers to parts of the chain complex here, and not the dimensions of the homology groups. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @AyushKhaitan Yes. It's a simple -yet a good- exercise to compute these homology groups.